# jointjs paper background color

Tags: javascript, css, svg, jointjs

I am designing a UI that uses jointjs to draw a graph.

I need to change the background color of the Paper but I see that changing the .viewport css (e.g. `background-color: #ff0000;` ) this doesn't affect the appearance of the svg.

How can I add color in the background of the jointjs Paper?

thanks

Comment: create a rect the size of the viewport and set it to the colour you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the answer. 
I don't see this as a clean approach, meaning that I should then keep track of another cell in case of resize etc. Are you sure there is no other way to do this?  thanks

Answer (score 3):

When initializing paper, add background option to paper

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    background: {
       color: '#ff0000'
    }                                                                         
});
```

You can find more info at [Jointjs paper documentation.](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.1/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.options.background)

Comment: To add to this, you can dynamically change the background after creation using `paper.drawBackground({ color: 'your_color' });`. See https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.1/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.drawBackground.

Answer (score 1):

The paper is just a normal HTML `<div>` element so you can set the `background-color: #ff00000` on that `<div>` element rather than on the internal `.viewport` SVG `<g>` element.

Comment: thanks. I had this approach in my first implementation but it has problems. For example, in case of window resizing the div get a relative size, while the svg will stay at the exact, defined, size that in cases go out of the space of div.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the svg element style in css to change the paper background color and it works for me. Here is an example.

```css
svg {
    background-color: blue;
}
```